# Implement Server side pagination in angular-datatable

Tags: angular, datatable, pagination

Implement server side pagination in angular data table. The table is not rendered properly. We have to change the response of the backend for the data table to work properly?
Below I provide what I tried. If any body tried angular with data table please guide me

```
<div class="container">
    <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Age</th> 
           <th>Country</th>      >
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
          <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.country }}</td>      
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

```
  dtOptions: any = {}

  @Input() users: User[]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      data: [],
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 2,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      responsive: true     
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.matchBids) {
      this.dtOptions.data = this.matchBids
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your question that may help you.

It is simple as it looks :)

So when you using Server-side data-tables with angular,
 In the.ts  component file when using ajax,
 instead, make a direct call to some URL.
 Just use a service that returns the observable (in my case).
 Here is a link to the data-tables demo that guided me:
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-server-side-1264

Code snippet:

```
   this.dtOptions.ajax = (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
      that.controllerService.getAdminControllers(this.dtOptions.pageLength,dataTablesParamete.start).subscribe(resp => {
          that.data = resp.data;
          callback({
            recordsTotal: resp.pagination.totalCount,
            recordsFiltered: resp.pagination.totalCount,
            data: []

          });
          console.log(that.data);
        });
    };
```